# Integrate Dropbox app in my app

Tags: objective-c, dropbox-api

So, this is the task I want to achieve. In my app, I have a text field which displays a list of all the apps and files that are present in my iOS device. One of them will be dropbox. When I tap on drop box, it should open the dropbox app and ask for user credentials. Once the user enters his credentials, it should save them and it shouldn't ask the next time he logs in again. Now, in that textbox that I mentioned earlier, I should get the list of the files that are there in my dropbox folder.

I'm new to iOS app development stuff so any help in the form of links, documentation will help alot. Please give me a brief idea on how to achieve this task.

Answer (score 4):

Since you said links:

**Tutorial Links**

- http://www.mathiastauber.com/integration-o-dropbox-in-your-ios-application/
- http://www.mathiastauber.com/integration-of-dropbox-in-your-ios-application-authentication/
- http://programmaticallytakingscreenshot.blogspot.com/2011/04/dropbox-integration-in-iphone.html

**Dropbox Links**

- http://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps
- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#ios

You should consider using `Table Views` to show your data instead of Text Fields.

- http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

Apple Documentation on Table Views:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Good luck with this!

Answer (score 2):

What you are proposing violates the sandboxing principle of iOS. Apps don't know about anything outside their own documents folder, and do not have permission to read or write outside the area.

Files stored in Dropbox are accessible via the Dropbox API, so you will be able to achieve that part of your design, but most of the other apps on the device will not be visible or accessible to you.

Comment: There are many apps available which does this thing. Like in some apps they have a button "login with Facebook" and when I tap on it, it opens the facebook app that is installed in my iOS device. When I click on the directions in my browser, it opens MAP app in the device and have that address in the search field. Isn't this the same ? I thought it is the same thing. As I said I am new to iOS, I don't really know if this thing is possible or not.

Comment: Those apps will all have published URL schemes that the phone will open, switching you to the app. My point is, you can't "display a list of all the apps and files present on the device".